# How can Colossus be dented?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016, colossus

OK, this is really crossing the boundaries of Marvel due to the fact that Colossus in Deadpool is always in metal form, but in Deadpool Colossus seems to have dents in him. I never thought he could have been dented permanently as Colossus seems to have in Deadpool.

Dent in his left arm,

[image]

I know in the comics that he has his bent and broken by "World Breaker Hulk",

[image]

But, there is not much on if dents will stay with him. Contrary to the comics and other Marvel movies Colossus does not change into human form in Deadpool, so I can only imagine that he has an injury of some sort to keep that dent???

Comment: He rips off Rockslide's arms, not Colossus': http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-wW1CS_TuO3c/TazKMe-5J6I/AAAAAAAADak/oUgVOtcm87E/s1600/Rockslide.jpg

Comment: Crap, I got that mixed up, he just bent them. Will update question to that effect.

Comment: I’m not clear what your question is. Are you asking how he got that dent? I don’t understand what the relevance is of the fact that he doesn’t change into human form in *Deadpool* either.

Comment: I think the relevance of the fact that he doesn't change back is that we never get to see if he has an existing injury/scar (i.e. does a scar inflicted on flesh become a dent in the metal form), or if it's something that auto-heals when he changes forms.

Comment: Perhaps some truly colossal acne?

Comment: @Broklynite: so would he use Clearasil or Brass-o?  :)

Comment: @Paul Brillo Pad soaked in alcohol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The mutant [Colossus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossus_(comics)) is very durable and capable of sustaining significant damage in his metallic form. Composed of "living osmium" his body can withstand punishing impacts, but he is not invulnerable. There is no reason to believe Colossus could not suffer minor "dents and dings" while in his metallic state.

The mechanics of his metallic form are rarely discussed but his physical durability has allowed him to survive conflicts with beings as powerful as the Juggernaut and the Hulk without sustaining long term injuries. He has survived both Havok and Cyclops' at point blank range and survived.

[image]

**Colossus's durability:**

> - In his armored form Colossus is highly resistant to most forms of bodily harm. His armor is capable of withstanding ballistic penetration, including that of a 110 millimeter Howitzer shell.
> - He could survive a collision with a loaded, one-ton flatbed truck at 100 miles per hour or an explosion of 450 pounds of TNT.
> - He can survive extremes of temperature from 70 degrees above absolute zero (-390 degrees Fahrenheit) to approximately 9000 Fahrenheit. (the freezing and melting points of metallic Osmium)

[image]

*In this instance, Colossus is heated to extreme temperatures but feels no pain.*

> - However, it is theorized that above the latter temperature, his armored form would begin to melt. Colossus's armored form cannot rust under normal Earth conditions.
> - Colossus has been injured by acid sufficiently that even when he returned to his Human form he remained deathly injured and required advanced medical care from the **[Shi'ar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shi%27ar)**.

[image]

[image]

Small injuries (in essence, dents and scratches) sustained in his metallic form are likely to stay there until he returns to his flesh and blood state. Such minor injuries suffered are erased during his transformation back to flesh.

Comment: What's the source on the quote of stats on his durability?

Comment: Right out of the Marvel Handbook, with the exception of the last point which occurred after the Handbook was written.